# Can't upload image and video from gallery in some Android mobiles

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-gallery, android-cursor

I am new to android development. I am working on images and videos in gallery. I upload the image or video from gallery. I got the cursor values return null.

First

1) Why the issue is occurred when upload image or video ?

2) How to solve this error?

I used to upload and image and video from gallery`

```
OpenGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mode = "sms";
                gocodercamera.stopPreview();


                isCameraMenuVisible = false;
                CameraMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(/*Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT*/Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 300);
            }
        });
`
```

OnActivityResult`

```
     /**Picking file from Gallery*/
        if (requestCode == 300) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                try {

                    gocodercamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    gocodercamera.startPreview();
                    if (data != null) {

                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String filepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();


                        if (filepath.endsWith(".jpg") || filepath.endsWith(".jpe") || filepath.endsWith(".jpeg") || filepath.endsWith(".png")) {

                            imagefilepath = filepath;
//                            uriList.add(imagefilepath);
//                            typesList.add("image");

                            Uri getCompressedUriPath = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                            String getCompressedPath = compressImage(filepath, getCompressedUriPath);
                            if (aDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                                sendMediaUpload(getCompressedPath, "image");
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }


//                            ImageAdapterList myAdapter = new ImageAdapterList();
//                            listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                        } else {

                            Cursor cursor1 = MediaStore.Video.query(getContentResolver(), selectedImage, new String[]{MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION});
                            cursor1.moveToFirst();
                            String dur = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex("duration"));
                            int duration = Integer.parseInt(dur);

                            duration = duration / 1000;

                            Log.e("dur", "dur : " + dur);
                            Log.e("duration", "duration : " + duration);


                            videofilepath = filepath;
                            imagefilepath = videofilepath;
                            sendMediaUpload(imagefilepath, "video");


//                                ImageAdapterList myAdapter = new ImageAdapterList();
//                                listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);


                        }
                    } else {
//                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! Failed to select File from gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                gocodercamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                gocodercamera.startPreview();
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User cancelled to select File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                gocodercamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                gocodercamera.startPreview();
//                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! Failed to select File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned Android 6.0, just check if you have the permissions given to read and write the disk storage before you try it. Starting from Marshmallow, Android has started runtime permissions which means by default most of the permissions provided in the Android Manifest does not actually work unless you provide it at runtime

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I mentioned the permission in manifest file. I set the target sdk 22.